# Capital cursive E in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, capitalization

How do I get a capital Cursive "E" in math mode? See picture encl.[image]

Comment: Is `\mathcal{E}` what you are looking for?

Comment: @T.Verron It doesn't look exatcly like that; I had the same idea.

Comment: Or are you actually looking for an `$\epsilon$`?

Comment: `\mathscr{E}` from the `mathrsfs` package it pretty close...

Comment: @CountZero That was my idea too (see, e.g., http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~vollmer/pdfs/typesetting-script.pdf).

Comment: What is the name of the book that the picture is from?

Comment: I tried searching for a while online to find this font, since it looks interesting. However, I have had absolutely no luck at all. It may be easiest to open up a high-resolution scan in Inkscape and vectorize the 'E' to generate an SVG image. You can clean up the edges and such if you notice any imperfections. Alternatively, you could try contacting the publisher and ask for the name of the font.

Comment: I had already tried `mathcal` and `mathscr` but as you can see, it isn't the same exact thing. Detexfy could only come up with `mathscr` and by the way, that was my first attempt. PS. I don't know how this question could be a duplicate question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several fonts that have cursive Es close to that in the sample.

#### Kunstlerscreibsch

http://www.font-db.com/font/kunstlerschreibschjoidbol/38809

[image]

#### Ecolier Court

(SIL license) http://www.fontspace.com/jean-douteau/ecolier
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that the E is derived from the one in this font? I don't see the resemblance...

Comment: @void-pointer - I've added an image: I think it is close.  There are several fonts in the collection.

Comment: I still think Ecolier (fontspace.com/jean-douteau/ecolier) is the closest one I've seen so far.

Comment: @void-pointer: I hadn't seen your comment on the other answer.  I'll CW this answer, so you can add other font possibilities to this answer.

Comment: After many months I solved the issue by including \usepackage[cal=boondoxo, calscaled=.98]{mathalfa} in the preamble of the **main.tex** file. It works just fine!

Comment: That first domain has been parked.  As of 2022, here's [another website](https://fontzone.net/font-details/kunstler-script) for Kuntsler Script.

Answer (score 19):

To assemble the suggestions in the comments, you can do the following:

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathrsfs} % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathrsfs

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \mathscr{E} % uses `mathrsfs`
  \mathcal{E}
  \varepsilon
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Output.]

As [void-pointer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5325/void-pointer) points out, the fonts [Cursif](http://www.fontspace.com/christophe-beaumale/cursif), [ALS Script](http://www.fontspace.com/digital-graphics-labs/als-script), and [Ecolier](http://www.fontspace.com/jean-douteau/ecolier) come even closer to the desired output.

Comment: Still closer are the following fonts: http://www.fontspace.com/christophe-beaumale/cursif, http://www.fontspace.com/digital-graphics-labs/als-script, http://www.fontspace.com/jean-douteau/ecolier. I don't think that the font used in OP's example is available online. It would be neat if someone could identify it.

Comment: @void-pointer Indded they are! I'll add a comment in my answer.

Comment: Svend, thanks for the links but are these fonts available as packages for LaTeX in the first place? Are they available in MATH MODE?

Answer (score 5):

I'd also recommend [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)! It allows you to draw a symbol and it shows you possible matches and the TeX required to draw them. It works very well, I use it all the time!