# How to change calligraphic capital letters in mathpazo?

Tags: math-mode, mathpazo, calligraphy

I'm trying to get the calligraphic capital "E". I really like `mathpazo` package but I'd like to change the way it renders calligraphic "E".

Below is a picture: when I type and compile `$\mathcal{E}$` I get center version *E*, instead I'd like the left-most *E*.

[image]

When I didn't have `mathpazo`, I solved this problem by loading package `mathalpha`. I have posted below a MWE (also see [this old question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111599/capital-cursive-e-in-math-mode)):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
%\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm, right=2cm, left=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo, calscaled=.98]{mathalfa}
\newcommand{\derivataparziale}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^{#1}{#2}}{\partial {#3}^{#1}} }

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{E}(y) = - \derivataparziale{}{V(y)}{y}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define `bondoxo` as `mathscript`:

\usepackage[scr=boondoxo, scrscaled=.98]{mathalfa}

and use it via `\mathscr`. This way you can use both fonts, if you wish.

Comment aside — the `esdiff` package makes it simpler to type partial derivatives, especially for crossed derivatives and specifying at which point the derivative is evaluated.

Comment: I wonder why it didn't take in `\usepackage[cal=boondoxo, calscaled=.98]{mathalfa}`, as written in my MWE, above. The solution you provided, ie. turning to `\mathscr{E}`, works. Mmm...who knows why?

Comment: I've just tested, and have no problem: it is `boondoxo`that appears as math calligraphic font. What happens to you is all the amore strange as I think `mathpazo`doesn't touch upon calligraphic fonts. Btw, I don't see why you scale `boondoxo` For me, no scaling is OK (checked with gsview).

Comment: Thank you for your input on package `esdiff`,  it's truly coming handy! Do you have any suggestion that might help with integrals too? For now, I'm going with `\newcommand{\integrale}[4]{\displaystyle \int_{#3}^{#4} {#1} \,\text{d}{#2}}`. Any suggestion is appreciated.;-)

Comment: Personally, I don't like very much this way of doing things, because it's a problem to share such files. In my opinion, it's more a question of setting up your editor. For instance, with my editor I could create a shortcut that inserts `\int_{}^{*} * \d *` with the cursor just between `\{` and the following `}`. Another shortcut lets me go to the next `*`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what editor are you using? What OS?

Comment: @WobbyWindows: WinEdt8.1 — and Windows 7 Pro. WinEdt has a power macro language (~ 1000), loads fast and is easy to configure. To give you an idea, I have managed to have a shortcut for, say, the letter `γ` (a lot of editors can do that), but saves it as `\gamma` so that it looks a little more to the final real formula (which is easier to read and check  in the editor), but latex can still compile it.

Answer (score 4):

The BOONDOX font has the suitable interface:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{BOONDOX-cal}
\newcommand{\derivataparziale}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^{#1}{#2}}{\partial {#3}^{#1}} }

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{E}(y) = - \derivataparziale{}{V(y)}{y}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mmm...doesn't work for me! Tried looking in the package manager `tlmgr --gui` (under Linux)-- the only package I searched out is called `boondox`. When I compile I get an error that says: "_Package textcomp Error: Symbol \textuparrow not provided by
(textcomp)                font family ppl in TS1 encoding._
_(textcomp)                Default family used instead._"

Comment: @WobbyWindows You have an outdated TeX distribution.

Comment: Don't know why, but your MWE's working on my system. Just wanted to let you know.